# How to save place for inserted image(on validation)?

Tags: html, css

I have inputs with jQuery validation and I'm inserting images, when input is required, but it add some margin, and moves my divs.

Here is my fields without validation:

[image]

and inputs with error:
[image]

I tried different variants: adding z-index, positioning, but couldn't do this.

Here is my html with errors:

```
   <form ... >
   <div class="field3">
 <div class="pickers">
<span id="pickers">From</span>
<input id="report_start_date" name="report[start_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker error"><label for="report_start_date" generated="true" class="error" style="">bla bla bla</label><
  </div>
   <div class="pickers"><span id="pickers">To</span>
  <input id="report_end_date" name="report[end_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker error"><label for="report_end_date" generated="true" class="error" style="">bla bla bla</label>

   </div>
   </div>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Run Report">
   </form>
```

And my css:

```
label.error {
background: url('../images/not_valid.png') no-repeat;
display:inline;
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 15px 0 5px 5px;
color:transparent;
 }
 label.valid {
background: url('../images/valid.png') no-repeat;
display:inline;
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 15px 0px 10px 50px;
width: 47px;
height: 36px;
 color:transparent;
 }
#pickers{
font-weight: bold;
}
.pickers{
display: inline;
padding-top: 5px;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning?

Comment: Do you mean to add position:absolute into my pickers div ?

Comment: No, to your `label`s. However make sure your layout has enough space for them to not obstruct other elements.

Comment: I added and it is working, but how I can move background now ?

Comment: What kind of background? Your question does not mention anything about backgrounds.

Comment: Excuse me, everything is ok. Thanks. I find it in w3schools. Please post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(copied from the question comment)

Try using `position: absolute` for the `label`s that contain the validation marker images. This way they will not take part in the normal layout and update it whenever you need to show/hide them.

Comment: I would think `visibility: hidden` and your `position:relative` would be the way to go here, right? Fairly sure its a w3c standard.. `position:absolute` seems kind of counter-intuitive --its deliberately **not** allocating room for the div.. Correct me if I'm wrong here though

Comment: With a high number of fields in a form, the OP will have to provide a distinct `label` next to every field. This impacts the DOM size and rendering speed, since a render object is created for every label (agree, these may be infinitesimal). The usual approach is to add markers only to fields that fail the validation.

Comment: fair enough. +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Position it however you want, and give it the css style `visibility:hidden;` that'll keep it part of the document flow while hiding it until you need it. Then, when you need it, use jQuery (or whatever you want to use -- jQuery is easiest) to un-hidden it.